# Trying to add files to a branch

Tags: git, github

I created a gh-pages branch of my repo, looking to create a github page for a project, as described at http://pages.github.com/.  The branch was created, but now I'm stucked on how to proceed. For example, how do I add the file index.html that currently lives in the master branch to the gh-pages branch? And what do I do after that?

After `git branch gh-pages` I entered `git checkout gh-pages` and `git add index.html`, but a `git status` showed

> nothing to commit

Comment: can you give complete output of `git status -s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New branches start out with all the files from original branch (in your case, the content of `gh-pages` branch is basically copied from the `master` branch). So the index.html file is already in `gh-pages` branch. Try add a new file and you'll see it in `git status` output.

Answer (score 0):

when you branch, the new branch contains everything in the branch you were in, the branch is nothing more than a pointer to a commit object. At the time of branching, they will point to the same object.

Once you make changes to files in the new branch, and commit them you will start to see changes between branches, but in the example above, you hadn't (presumably) actually made any changes to index.html.

Try editing the index.html file, add some code, add and commit it.

Now do `git diff master` and you should see your changes